# Toggle class between two buttons in Angular but restrict to prevent same button from changing class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

Trying to create some very basic functionality which basically makes two buttons behave like radio buttons. Have two buttons that are used to show/hide different content based on what is shown. So it is working as expected except for it is changing on any click. So if I click the same button twice then it changes the class. I only need it to change if the other button is clicked:

```
<button class="someClass" ng-class="{true: 'green', false: 'blue'}        [!yupNope.isSelected]" ng-click="yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected">YES</button>
   <button class="someClass" ng-class="{false: 'green', true: 'yupNope'}[!yupNope.isSelected]" ng-click="yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected">NO</button>
```

So if Yes is clicked then it should update and No should too. But if Yes is clicked again before No is clicked then there should be no change.

Here is a Plunkr to play with:

[Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hDVCYaQVyTaxrE4IZOl?p=preview)

Comment: simple assing static value like _true_ or _false_ instead `yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to `ng-click` expression:

```
<button class="someClass" ng-class="{true: 'green', false: 'blue'}[!yupNope.isSelected]" 
  ng-click="yupNope.isSelected ? (yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected) : ''">YES</button>
 <button class="someClass" ng-class="{false: 'green', true: 'yupNope'}[!yupNope.isSelected]" 
  ng-click="!yupNope.isSelected ? (yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected) : ''">NO</button>
```

Your modified [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yET5B6kqAHTlMmrM9bAT?p=preview).

Comment: Admittedly dfsq's answer's better :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected` as `ngClick` expression set `yupNope.isSelected` to true/false respectively:

```
<button ng-click="yupNope.isSelected = false" class="someClass" ng-class="{true: 'green', false: 'blue'}[!yupNope.isSelected]">YES</button>
<button ng-click="yupNope.isSelected = true" class="someClass" ng-class="{false: 'green', true: 'yupNope'}[!yupNope.isSelected]">NO</button>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/HJfmYf6d9dnNqZLwYLFF?p=preview

Comment: i'm so slow write answer :-)

Comment: @Grundy Sorry, next time  you will beat me ;)

Comment: I'll be faster next time :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using ng-disabled. On each button you can apply the ng-disabled attribute.

```
<button class="someClass"
    ng-class="{true: 'green', false: 'blue'}[!yupNope.isSelected]" 
    ng-click="yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected"
    ng-disabled="yupNope">YES</button>

<button class="someClass"
    ng-class="{false: 'green', true: 'yupNope'}[!yupNope.isSelected]"
    ng-click="yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected"
    ng-disabled="!yupNope">NO</button>
```

You can find the docs here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled